# Condense Duplicate Rows into Unique Rows with if

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements

So have a situation where:

**DataFrame:**

```
dat <- data.frame(colA = rep(c(0,1,0), c(6,1,8)), 
                  colB = rep(c(1,0,1,0), c(1,4,1,9)), 
                  colC = rep(c(0,1,0), c(9,1,5)), 
                  colD = rep(c(0,1,0), c(8,1,6)), 
                  colE = rep(0, 15), 
                  color = rep(c("blue","red","yellow"), each=5), 
                  colorId = rep(c(22,40,35), each=5))

colA   colB    colC    colD   colE   color   colorId
0      1       0       0      0      Blue    22
0      0       0       0      0      Blue    22
0      0       0       0      0      Blue    22
0      0       0       0      0      Blue    22
0      0       0       0      0      Blue    22
0      1       0       0      0      Red     40
1      0       0       0      0      Red     40
0      0       0       0      0      Red     40
0      0       0       1      0      Red     40
0      0       1       0      0      Red     40
0      0       0       0      0      Yellow  35
0      0       0       0      0      Yellow  35
0      0       0       0      0      Yellow  35
0      0       0       0      0      Yellow  35
0      0       0       0      0      Yellow  35
```

**End Goal**

```
colNames      color   colorId
colB          Blue    22
colB          Red     40
colA          Red     40
colD          Red     40
colC          Red     40
None          Yellow  35
```

Here is the approach I started taking, and then questioned myself into confusion. Not shown below, I created another column that summed the binary values of the 'col' columns using rowSums (dat$rowsu <- rowSums(dat[1:4]==1)).

I was thinking to write a function, where if there was more than 0 colorId duplicate counts, then keep any rows where the rowsu > 0, and in the special case as Yellow, if they're all 0 and the overall rowsu = 0, then just keep one row out of all the duplicates for something similar to below. (Having trouble on coding this part though if it is the issue)

```
colA   colB    colC    colD   colE   color   colorId
0      1       0       0      0      Blue    22
0      1       0       0      0      Red     40
1      0       0       0      0      Red     40
0      0       0       1      0      Red     40
0      0       1       0      0      Red     40
0      0       0       0      0      Yellow  35
```

Secondly, for the latter issue of creating the column with the names, still thinking about an if function where using the colname name to be extracted into the row name if it has a 1 under it? Not sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A possible solution with the `data.table`-package:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)[, .(colNames = {cs <- colSums(.SD == 1) > 0;
                           if(sum(cs) > 0) names(.SD)[cs] else 'None'})
           , by = .(color, colorId)]
```

which gives:

> ```
>     color colorId colNames
> 1:   blue      22     colB
> 2:    red      40     colA
> 3:    red      40     colB
> 4:    red      40     colC
> 5:    red      40     colD
> 6: yellow      35     None
> ```

What this does:

- `setDT(dat)` converts `dat` to a *'data.table'* (which is an enhanced form of a *data.frame*).
- `data.tble`-syntax works like [`dat[i, j, by]` (see 1b for an explanation)](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html). In this case, `dat` is grouped by `color` and `colorId` ( the `by = .(color, colorId)`-part).
- For each group, `colSums(.SD == 1) > 0` checks whether the `colA` to `colE` colums contain a `1`. The resulting logical vector is temporarily stored as `cs`. `.SD` stands for **S**ubset of **D**ata (see 2b under the link in the previous point).
- Finally we check whether at least one of the columns has a `1` with `sum(cs) > 0`. If that is the case the respective columnnames are returned by `names(.SD)[cs]` and if the condition doesn't hold `None` is returned.

---

Using `dplyr` from the `tidyverse` you can get the same result with:

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>% 
  group_by(color, colorId) %>% 
  do(data.frame(colNames = {cs <- colSums(. == 1) > 0;
                            if(sum(cs) > 0) names(.)[cs] else 'None'}))
```

Comment: Thanks @Jaap! Worked perfectly. Possible to break down this code by how it works?

Comment: @S31 Added an explanation, HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option with `tidyverse` where we `gather` the columns 'colA' to 'colE' to long format, grouped by 'color', 'colorId', create 'None' as the 'colNames' `if` all the 'val' are 0.  Get the `distinct` rows and `filter` for rows having 'val' as 1 or 'colNames' as 'None' and `select` the columns of interest and `arrange` if needed

```
library(tidyverse)
dat %>%
    mutate_at(vars(color, colorId), funs(factor(., levels = unique(.)))) %>% 
    gather(colNames, val, colA:colE) %>% 
    group_by(color, colorId) %>% 
    mutate(colNames = if(all(val==0)) "None" else colNames) %>% 
    distinct %>%
    filter(val == 1| colNames == "None") %>% 
    select(colNames, color, colorId) %>%
    arrange(color, colNames)
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups: color, colorId [3]
#  colNames color  colorId
#  <chr>    <fctr> <fctr> 
#1 colB     blue   22     
#2 colA     red    40     
#3 colB     red    40     
#4 colC     red    40     
#5 colD     red    40     
#6 None     yellow 35
```